# How to use the result from comparing 2 forms and set fields in 3rd form in BMC Remedy AR System?

Tags: remedy

Please see the below scenario

1. I have forms A, B, and C.
2. I search B using fields from A to get a result list.
3. The result list contains one column with IDs from form C.
4. Now, I want get a field from A, set it in C for only those IDs returned by B.

I know it is confusing, but I have made it as simple as possible. Please help me accomplish the above operation in BMC Remedy Developer Studio (AR System)

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear, but I think that I understand your need. I think the primary issue is that you are thinking in terms of the GUI (results lists, active links, etc.). Instead you need to think of server-side workflow, filters and escalations. The other key is to use hidden fields to hold your IDs, data to push, flags.

I'm not sure what your trigger will be to make this all happen, so that will change the workflow. You could start with an entry A being created/modified. This will trigger a filter that does a set fields action querying B to pull back the IDs and save them into a hidden field. You then have another filter on A that checks for a value in the hidden ID field. It does a push fields action to save the data from A into the correct entry of C.

That's the basic idea which could be improved with a better understanding of the fields and flow.